# What widget can be used to implement a clickable Roulette table?

Tags: android, android-widget

In Java Swing, I could use JPanel to customize the click button for each area in the table; however there is no such equivalent JPanel for Android. So what's widget should I use to implement this type of behavior? More specifically, each number in the table should be clickable.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make them custom buttons in a `TableLayout` or use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) and incorporate it like a `ListView`